# Blender won't let me make things black

Tags: materials

I'm new to blender, and I'm doing alright, except for one annoying thing: random things just won't turn black. I literally just try to make a black line and I've fiddled with all the settings but it just stays this weird light grey. I also copy some tutorials and I can't make things black like they have it. It just stays light grey.

Comment: Which version?  Hit Z and choose rendered or material preview.  Still not black?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the said black line and its material properties.

Comment: What kind of shading setup do you have? In the right upper corner there is some setting that let you see materials.